# LazyInitializationException when accessing @Id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

We are getting org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException in our wicket/spring/hibernate app. This happens rarely, maybe every 100th time the code runs.

At first, we got the exception when we accessed the lazy loaded objects data (also about every 100th time the code runs). So we thought the problem would be fixed if we manually load the object in to memory by getting it from the database with its id. Our understanding is that the field annotated with `javax.persistence.Id` should always be in memory. To our surprise we still get the exception **when accessing the id**. Maybe an example will make it more clear..

These are our POJO's:

```
public abstract class SuperDimension{ 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "Dimension_id_gen", strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "Dimension_id_gen", strategy = "uuid")
    protected String UUID;

   /*getters, setters and abstract stuff*/

}

public class Dimension extends SuperDimension{

    private String number;

    /*getters, setters and overridden methods*/
}

public class DimensionHolder{

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "myDim")
    private Dimension myDim;

    /*getters, setters*/
}
```

We have an instance of DimensionHolder and want to get its Dimension (myDims) number. At first we did this:

```
dimensionHolder.getMyDim().getNumber();
```

This caused (every 100th time) lazy init exception on .getNumber(). This is when we tried loading it manually before accessing number:

```
Dimension freshDimensionFromDataBase = dataBase.getDimensionFromUUID(dimensionHolder.getMyDim().getUUID);
String number = freshDimensionFromDataBase.getNumber();
```

This still causes lazy init exception on .getUUID(). Even if myDim is a proxy, shouldn't the id still be availible?

Is it possible that problem is that the id is in Dimensions super class and that the current instance of Dimension that we are using is a proxy object from hibernate? This sounds strange in our ears aswell, so maybe some kind soul can shed some light upon our problem?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: here's the stacktrace:

```
Root cause: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session Root Cause Message: LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
Message: WicketRuntimeException: Method onRequest of interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at eyesys.web.invoice.invoice.InvoicePage$20 {event='onclick'} on component [WebMarkupContainer [Component id = okayButton]] threw an exception
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:270)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:255)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:781)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:255)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:212)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:283)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:185)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:600)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1703)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by:

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:260)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:255)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:781)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:255)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:212)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:283)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:185)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:600)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1703)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by:

    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    at eyesys.domain.Dimension3_$$_javassist_17.getUUID(Dimension3_$$_javassist_17.java)
    at eyesys.web.invoice.invoice.lines2.AccountingLineRow$33.validate(AccountingLineRow.java:918)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.validateFormValidator(Form.java:1826)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.validateFormValidators(Form.java:1839)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form$17.component(Form.java:1865)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form$17.component(Form.java:1853)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:273)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrder(Visits.java:244)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.validateNestedForms(Form.java:1851)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.validate(Form.java:1715)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:803)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:762)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:158)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:184)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:369)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:260)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:255)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:781)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:255)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:212)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:283)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:185)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:600)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1703)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

AccountingLineRow = DimensionHolder.

Dimension3 = Dimension.

Comment: can you post the stacktrace ?

Comment: LazyInitializationException always happens when you close the sessions before you first time access to child elements which are loaded by lazy loading. Your code sniplet is not long enough to see where this might happen.

Comment: Added the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the proxy is initialized, whatever te method you call. And there might be a good reason to do so. For example, your `getId()` method could contain the following instructions:

```
public void getId() {
    LOG.debug("getId() called for entity with ID " + this.id + " and name " + name);
    return this.id;
}
```

If the proxy was not initialized, the logged name would be null, which would be incorrect.

I've read somewhere that the proxy is not initialized when calling `getId()` if you use property access type rather than field access type (i.e. if your getters are annotated with mapping annotations rater than your fields).

But I would simply initialize the object before closing the session, instead of initializing it after, by issuing a new sessio and a new database query.

Comment: "If the proxy was not initialized, the logged name would be null, which would be incorrect." - But it's the Id we are trying to access, not the name. From stacktrace:´  eyesys.domain.Dimension3_$$_javassist_17.getUUID(Dimension3_$$_javassist_17.java)´.